# Postgresql: checking if values exist in full table efficiently

Tags: postgresql, amazon-redshift

We have a transaction table of sale to customers with over 2000 million rows on Redshift. Every months transaction table has 5 million rows. For MIS (monthly 5 million rows only), I need to check if a customer is new based on mobile number, or the mobile number exists in the 2000 million database without joining it on the full table so my query remains efficient.

What I have tried:

newtable=`SELECT DISTINCT(mobile_no) as mobile_no,'old' as category FROM table`

maintable=`SELECT maintable.*, coalesce(nq.category,'new')
FROM maintable as maintable
LEFT JOIN (newquery) as nq on nq.mobile_no=maintable.mobile_no`;

This is very slow takes over 50 mins. I also tried
`SELECT exists (SELECT 1 FROM newtable WHERE mobile_no=maintable.mobile_no LIMIT 1) as as category` but this gives an 'out of memory' error.

Comment: You will almost certainly be faster joining the tables.

Comment: What are the sort and distribution keys for newtable and maintable? It can help to make `mobile_no` both sort. and dist key.

Also, you may need to collect statistics on both tables prior to query execution.

Comment: Redshift or Postgres? Although they share some ancient roots they are very different products.

Comment: I am using Redshift;
@BartSchuijt: Good suggestion; though bulk of the organisation is querying on sku id and location code so I doubt my admin will allow to change the sort key

Answer (score 0):

Amazon RedShift is a data warehouse, so it won't be fast on queries by design. If you will be doing analysis on the data and expect a faster result, you might want to explore other products they offer such as EMR to do your queries faster.

Here is a reference on what each service is intention is: https://aws.amazon.com/big-data/datalakes-and-analytics/